# Help explaining "reactive power" video: lights do not use any power?

Tags: power, electromagnetism

In the following video the poster wonders whether his lights, which do not seem to consume any power are running on "reactive power":

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbKr7aYKSPU

Is the poster of the video a con artist?  There are videos of similar experiments on YouTube, does that lend credence to the above video?  If not, are all posters of such videos conspiring together? What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is:  We don't know and we can't know, given the information in that video.

The only claim the video makes is that it is "reactive power", which is entirely different than "scalar waves".  But even then, there is nothing we can say about that claim as well.

The reason for this is simple:  The video just doesn't give us enough information to know what is going on.  We don't know what the schematic for the circuit is.  We don't know where the power is ultimately coming from.  We don't know where the wires are hooked up.  We don't know the type of lamps used.  We don't know the characteristics of the transformer.  For all we know, the Professor and Gilligan could be just out of shot on a bamboo bicycle hooked up to a generator.

Additionally, YouTube is full of videos just like this that have been complete hoaxes-- hoaxes that were admitted by the maker of the video.  Youtube cannot, and never has been, a repository of credible information.  If you doubt RationalWiki, then you must doubly-doubt Youtube.  At least RationalWiki has a chance in hell of getting bad information corrected.

Comment: Extra +1 for bamboo bicycle

Answer (score 3):

My immediate guess is that they're not using True-RMS multimeters.

If they're driving the coil with a unusual waveform, the meter will not read the current draw/voltage accurately at all. This is a common practice with free-energy cranks to get apparent "free" energy, that is really just hidden in the non-sinusoidal portion of the waveform.

Crappy multimeters simply measure peak-peak voltage, and divide by \$\sqrt2\$. Obviously, you can deliver a LOT more power, if your drive source is a square wave, rather then a sine wave, and still get the same measurement.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a good demonstration of reactive power, but it's not very well presented. Con men can work it by describing it improperly.

What is apparently being done is that the lights are being operated through a transformer, which can be taken apart--the primary can be separated from the secondary.  With the primary pulled out, all he has in his hand is an inductor being fed by AC.

Given the lack of details, I'll just say that what I'm about to explain applies to the setup as I described it.  If he's doing something else, then it won't apply to that, but it still applies to the experiment that I'm describing.

The "surprise" factor is the measurement of the current through the primary coil.  The challenge is stated as "Why doesn't the current increase when I set it down and the lights come on?"  To understand the nature of reactive power, it is better to ask, "Why doesn't the current fall off when he pulls the primary away?"

The answer lies in the nature of power calculations: **Current is not power.**  *Current times voltage* is power.  And in an AC circuit, you have to measure the phase angle between the voltage and the current to determine the real power being consumed.  "Real" power does work.  It lights lights, and it makes heat.  When he decouples the transformer, the voltage and current go out of phase, and the real power disappears (except for some losses that will indeed warm up the primary coil).  What you're left with is known in the business as "imaginary power". If you measure volts times amps without looking at the phase, it multiplies out to a number that sure looks like power, but it isn't there.  When the current is at its peak, the voltage is zero.  When the voltage is at its peak, the current is zero.  And the current that flows into the coil flows right back out on the next half-cycle, without having done any work.

It's not a simple concept.  Most of us don't see this until we begin to study electrical engineering.